# Compiling FreeRTOS in IAR7.5 from IAR4.0 - Cstartup.s79 error

Tags: assembly, arm, iar, freertos

I am trying to recompile a (modified) FreeRTOS project from IAR4.0 to IAR7.5 and am getting errors in Cstartup.s79 of the type described [here](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/April_2006/freertos_include_files_1487328.html):

Is there a suitable version of Cstartup.s79 anywhere for versions of IAR beyond 4.0? I am not familiar with ARM Assembler and running out of time.

The relevant information in the link is:

If I copy intrinsics.h to intrinsic.h, C-compilation seems to work, but I still get these assembler errors:

> Error[116]: Section type missing
>   FreeRTOSV4.1.3\FreeRTOS\Demo\uIP_Demo_IAR_ARM7\SrcIAR\Cstartup.s79 34 
>   Error[116]: Section type missing
>   FreeRTOSV4.1.3\FreeRTOS\Demo\uIP_Demo_IAR_ARM7\SrcIAR\Cstartup.s79 35 
>   Error[40]: Bad instruction
>   FreeRTOSV4.1.3\FreeRTOS\Demo\uIP_Demo_IAR_ARM7\SrcIAR\Cstartup.s79 41 
>   Warning[24]: ENDMOD directive is ignored (only one module is allowed)
>   FreeRTOSV4.1.3\FreeRTOS\Demo\uIP_Demo_IAR_ARM7\SrcIAR\Cstartup.s79 220
>
> It seems it doesn't like these lines: RSEGINTRAMSTART_REMAP
>   RSEGINTRAMEND_REMAP org0 ENDMOD

Comment: *"am getting errors in Cstartup.s79 of the type described here"* Why didn't you just paste the exact error messages you're getting into your question? Which errors on the linked page are you actually getting? Did you notice the response there that: *"The intrinsic functions __enable_interrupt and __disable_interrupt are
no longer available as intrinsic functions; however, they are available as library
functions, which means they are backwards compatible on source code level."*

Comment: @CodyGray Description updated

Answer (score 1):

Example cstartup.s files can be found in your ewarm installation. Look in `src/lib/arm` if you have an ARM-capable devices (Cortex-A/R or legacy devices) or `src/lib/thumb` if you have a Cortex-M device.

That said, there are two major technology steps between ewarm 4.1 and ewarm 7.5 so you should expect more problems than the cstartup.s issue. There is a migration guide in the documentation catalog and it covers both the step from 4.x to 5.x and 5.x to 6.x (7.x is essentially the same as 6.x).

Comment: Thanks. However, the assembler file I am having problems with is supplied by an old version of FreeRTOS. Newer versions are not of any use unless I do a complete re-port of the OS, which is not going to happen. If I cannot get a fix for this I will revert to using IAR 4.0

Comment: @DirkBruere Check the migation guide, it covers the main differences between the major versions of the compiler.

Comment: I have done that, and it tells me what assembler directives have been changed or removed. Problem is that I do not have time to learn ARM assembler, new IAR directives and then work out what is wrong with the original file/module and fix it. Other people must have solved this problem - I'm looking for copypasta

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as suggested by IAR is to go back to using 4.41. Hooray. Or pay someone to do the port from EWARM 4.41 to 7.8

That was well worth the £1500 a year support we pay them.